# Does SO-DIMM DDR3 from Macbook fit into normal Motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

Do SO-DIMM DDR3 from a macbook pro fit and work on a "normal" motherboard like this one:

http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.de.asp?Model=AD2550B-ITX

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Says that it does on the specifications. "Normal" motherboards use full sized DIMMs but a lot of mini ITX boards, especially ones that run an atom processor use sodimm ram, including this one.

The ram certainly should fit, and very likely would work.